# Construct a Random graph from the degree distribution,

Tags: graph-theory

How to construct a random graph G based on the unique knowledge of the degree distribution (the probability distribution of the degrees) ?

Answer (score 1):

See

http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~sourav/beam-yale-trans.pdf